# UITextView visually changing content position when pasting in text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView which is designed to enlarge to fit the contentView when needed. When I paste in a paragraph of text, however, it puts the start and end points of the content vertically in the wrong places. Entering or deleting a character resets it back to the correct position.

Any ideas why this is?

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(
        self.textView.frame.origin.x,
        self.textView.frame.origin.y,
        self.textView.frame.size.width,
        self.textView.contentSize.height + HEADER_ADDITIONAL_HEIGHT);

    self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    self.previousContentSize = textView.contentSize;
}
```

Comment: could you include a screenshot that shows the expected and actual results of pasting text?

Answer (score 1):

When I used:

```
textView.contentSize = textView.frame.size;  
textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

It solved my issue, but created a new issue where we sometimes get weird scrolling while typing or deleting text. So, I used this:

```
textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( textView.contentSize.width,
                                   textView.contentSize.height+1);
```

This also solved the issue. I think what we all need here is the effect which we get whenever the `contentSize` of a textview is changed. Unfortunately, I do not know what this effect is. If somebody knows, please tell.

Update:
I have found a method which you can use to solve your issue (I used this to resolve mine). 
You can ask NSLayoutMAnager to refresh the entire layout:

```
[textView.textStorage edited:NSTextStorageEditedCharacters range:NSMakeRange(0, textView.textStorage.length) changeInLength:0];
```

NSLayoutManager attempts to avoid refreshing the layout because it's time consuming and takes a lot of work, so it's set up to only do it when absolutely necessary (lazily).
There are a number of `invalidateLayout` functions related to this class but none of them cause an actual re-layout when called.

Answer (score -1):

I know this comes late, but I ran into this issue and thought I should share what I came up with in case others find themselves in the same situation.

You are on the right track, but in `textViewDidChange:` you are missing one important thing: setting the contentSize after updating the frame height.

```
// I used 0.f for the height, but you can use another value because according to the docs:
//  "the actual bounding rectangle returned by this method can be larger 
//    than the constraints if additional space is needed to render the entire 
//    string. Typically, the renderer preserves the width constraint and 
//    adjusts the height constraint as needed."
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(textview.frame.size.width, 0.f);
CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:size
                                   options:OptionsYouNeedIfAny // NSStringDrawingOptions
                                   context:nil];

// Where MinTextViewHeight is the smallest height for a textView that 
//   your design can handle
CGFloat height = MAX(ceilf(rect.size.height), MinTextViewHeight); 
CGRect rect = textView.frame;
rect.size.height = height;
textView.frame = rect;

// Adjusting the textView contentSize after updating the frame height is one of the things you were missing
textView.contentSize = textView.frame.size;
textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

I hope this helps!

[See the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a) for more info about using `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`.